# Right div with variable width, left div takes remaining width

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` (.container) of variable width containing 2 `divs`.  The right `div` (.div-submit) is of variable width, depending on the language used.  I want the left `div` (div-textarea) to adjust and take all the remaining space on the left.  How can I achieve this without using flexboxes? See code below and this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gahilo/L3Wxd/2/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div-textarea">
        <textarea id="txtarea" placeholder="This  is a textarea"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="div-submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Post">
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note that the right `div` does not have a fixed width, so solutions like
[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106339/how-to-make-inner-left-div-take-up-100-minus-right-side-fixed-width-div) does not work.

Thanks.

Comment: Use display:table for your container and display:table-cell for your inner divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the `float:left;` from your textarea div and added `overflow:hidden;`. I have also repositioned the submit div in the HTML so that it is placed before the textarea div. It seems to work fine.

[Please see my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3Wxd/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display:table;` eg:

```
.container{
background-color: green;
display:table;
}

.div-textarea{
display:table-cell;
background-color: blue;
opacity: 0.5;
width:100%;
}

.div-submit{
display:table-cell;
background-color: red;
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Hope this helps!

****Edit****

Wrap the `div-text area` and the `div-submit` with another div and set it's display to `display:table-row;`

Comment: This does unfortunately force the right-side div to be squeezed down to the smallest possible size to fit, in terms of wrapping. So just putting "hello world" in the right div will have "hello" and "world" wrapped on separate lines. So long as your individual content boxes inside the right div do have exact widths (you just don't know the sum of a variable number of elements), you're fine. Or rely on `white-space: nowrap` for text-based content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, if it can help you: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3Wxd/6/)

I have changed the widths in `%` instead of `pixels` and used `text: no-wrap`